# permanently request without page reload

Tags: php

my web provider is Strato.
I would like to make an mysql select query every 10 seconds without page reload:

Websocket is not possible by Strato.
Alternative for me was ajax polling.
I tried this:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "ajax/mysqlQuery.php",
   data: 'userID=10'
}).done(function(result) {
      if(result) {
         // DO SOMETHING
      }
})
```

**mysqlQuery.php**

```
<?php

$data= null;

include("../inc/config.php");

while(!$data) {
    sleep(10);

    $statement = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE userID = ?");
    $statement->bind_param("s", $_POST["userID"]);
    $statement->execute();
    $result = $statement->get_result();

    while($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
        $data[] = array("ID" => $row->ID);
    }

}

echo json_encode($data);


?>
```

And this works fine.
BUT:

Strato has a php max_execution_time of 120 seconds.
My script works 120 seconds wery well - and than it will stop.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: why is there a `while(!$data){ ... }`?

Comment: Why not call $.ajax every 10 seconds instead?

Comment: Pardon? You want to execute every 10 seconds a script that needs more than 2 minutes to complete?

Comment: Can you please answer a possible way as answer? I would like to get each 10 seconds the data from mysql, without reloading the whole page :)

Comment: Create a timer in Ajax to call your PHP every 10 seconds, lose the `sleep()` in your PHP, and that should do it, surely? You could lose the `*` from the query as well, as you only seem to retrieve the ID column. And the `while()` loop could go, because presumably `userID` is unique in the table. So you probably don't need an array to return a single id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any actual polling within your JS code, eg. not a `setInterval` or stuff like that. To actually run a JS function every 10 seconds you should need something as following:

```
const doRequest = () => {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax/mysqlQuery.php",
    data: 'userID=10'
  }).done(function(result) {
    if (result) {
      // DO SOMETHING
    }
  });
}

setInterval(doRequest, 1000);
```

Regarding the PHP part, I don't think you need a `while(!$data){ ... }` in your script, as it will be evaluated only when an AJAX call will be made, so you can actually get rid of it.

I've modified a few things in you PHP code which I will explain

```
<?php
// just leave it alone at the beginning
include("../inc/config.php");

$statement = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE userID = ?");
$statement->bind_param("s", $_POST["userID"]);
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->get_result();

$data = null;
// maybe you can use $result->fetch_assoc() directly instead of returning an object and mapping it back to an associative array
while($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
    $data[] = array("ID" => $row->ID);
}

// close the statement for better PHP performances
$statement->close();

// return it
echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

If your script will continue taking more than 2mins to answer, probably there's something wrong with the DB, or its just the hosting which is throttling your script

As a side note
if you expect an array from your PHP code, you can also set `$data = []` as default, so if nothing gets returned, you won't need to edit stuff inside your JS code, for example checking if the result is actually an array and so on...